# git push - updates rejected because tip of current branch behind remote counterpart

Tags: git

I created a new branch and made changes to the code and attempted to push

```
git add .
git checkout -b newbranch
git commit -m "commit"
git push origin newbranch
```

I get `error : failed to push some refs .. updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind its remote counterpart..`

if I do `git pull` or `git pull --rebase`, I get

```
there is no tracking information for the current branch. Please specify which branch you want to merge with
```

if I try `git rebase origin/main` and `git pull origin main --rebase`, it says

```
current branch newbranch is up to date
```

if I try `git pull origin/main` and `git pull main`, it says

```
fatal: origin/main does not appear to be a git repository
```

if I try `git pull origin main`, it says

```
fatal: not possible to fast-forward, aborting
```

can anyone help?

Comment: Consider `git pull origin newbranch`.

Comment: I don't know why this got so many downvotes. The scenario is not that surprising a mistake to make. Upvoting both the question and TTT's excellent answer.

Answer (score 4):

The title error message is likely because you created a branch with the same name as one that already exists on the remote. So when you attempt to push it Git is informing you that there are commits on the remote tracking branch with that name that you do not have yet.

You can confirm by listing all the remote branches with `git branch -r`.

If that's the problem there are lots of things you can do to solve this. Some of them are:

1. Rename your branch to something else. Then when you push it you won't conflict with an already existing branch.
2. If you feel your branch should get the new commits from the remote branch, then perform `git pull origin newbranch` to merge them in (or use `git pull --rebase origin newbranch` if you don't want to create a merge commit for this). After that you'll be able to cleanly push.
3. If your intent was to blow those commits away on the remote branch, then you could do a force push, with `git push --force-with-lease`. If that still failed then it means there are commits on the remote repo that you haven't even fetched yet, so you would need to `git fetch` (and probably look at the commits to make sure you don't want them) and then perform the force push again.

I'm not sure which option is best for you, but I definitely would **not** do #3 unless you know for sure you don't need what's on the remote branch of the same name. If you aren't sure which is best I'd lean towards option #1, for now.

Comment: Yes, the branch name is same causes the problem on my side, thanks.